# Azure bash task not showing full git log output

Tags: git, azure

I have written a script to get the full git log between two commits and format it.
But when running `git log` in an Azure Bash task it is only showing one commit.

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
  targetType: 'inline'
  script: |
    lastTag="tag/${{ parameters.PreviousReleaseVersion }}"
    currentTag="tag/${{ parameters.ReleaseVersion }}"
    echo previous release: "$lastTag"
    echo next release: "$currentTag"
                
    git log --format='%H' $lastTag..$currentTag
```

Output:

```
 previous release: tag/2022....

 next release: tag/2022...

 a2ea57fea.. # rest of commit hash
```

Locally the script is working, and git log shows all commits.

Comment: This just means that the Git repository in question contains only one commit and/or that there is only one commit in the provided range. Since CI systems often make *shallow clones* that have only one commit, if you're sure the range should have more, it's probably that your CI system has made a shallow clone. Get your CI system to stop doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction, I've added `git checkout -f master` and `git pull --rebase origin master` and now it is able to find all commits.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Removed image and added text from the bash output in azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torek provided the answer about the repo only being a shallow clone.

Adding `git checkout -f master` and `git pull --rebase origin master` before running `git log` solved the issue.

Or even better:
`git fetch --unshallow`